# How to hide remote address from inspect network headers. From nginx configuration

Tags: nginx-config

My web application of IP address shown in network headers from inspect. I want hide them for security purposes. What is the property I need to set in nginx's configuration?

```
location / {

    proxy_set_header                Host $host;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #proxy_set_header               X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    real_ip_header                  X-Forwarded-For;

    }
```

I tried the above configuration script but remote address are getting same.

Comment: Can you please update which network header, is displaying the IP?

Comment: Right Click and then inspect on any web page then go to Network Tab. Then use ctrl+r key...then select first item...Then you will get Remote address under headers.

Comment: I believe that's the DNS resolution of the domain and it cannot be hidden anyways, as that's how the client would connect to your server.